# Is iterator to a container with incomplete data type legal?

Tags: c++, iterator, incomplete-type

Is the following code legal?

```
class A
{
    std::map<int, A>::iterator x;
};
```

Visual Studio 2015 accepts it, but clang says

```
.../ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/utility:254:9:  
error: field has incomplete type 'A'
    _T2 second;
    ^
....
a.cpp:52:21:
note: definition of 'A' is not complete until the closing '}'
    struct A
           ^
```

Edit:
The problem seems to be with the standard library, http://rextester.com/QNNEG57036 fails on it

My question is whether the code is legal or not, not how to fix it (ex. by changing compiler flags).

Comment: clang 3.8 compiles such code without errors

Comment: @user1034749: I didn't check which container it is, it actually complains only on map

Comment: Does it complains on list?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: no

Comment: The code compiles both on [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/83E9Em) and [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/V4fVyi).

Comment: @skypjack: I think it has to do with `libcxx`, I added a link to a compiler that fails on it.

Comment: @Dani Looks `like c++ std library` variant is also important, because of with `gcc`'s `libstdc++` your code with vector and map compiled without problem by `clang`

Comment: @Dani Nope, the link succeed as well here. It compiles and print _Hello, world!_.

Comment: @skypjack: It seems I linked the default file. Updated the link now.

Comment: @user1034749: How can I check its version? It came with the ndk I'm using.

Comment: @Dani It's due to the `-stdlib=libc++` flag to the compiler, remove it and the error will disappear.

Comment: @skypjack: I need to use `libc++`... My question is whether the code is legal or not, not how to fix it. If it is legal, it is a bug in `libc++`

Comment: @Dani I guess [9.2/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#class.mem-6) states when a class is considered a complete type in regard of its members.

Comment: @skypjack: I would expect a `map` to function with an incomplete type just like `list` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless explicitly stated in the standard that incomplete types are legal, they are not legal. The specific section is 17.6.4.8 [res.on.functions] paragraph 2:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> [...]
>
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

I don't think any of containers is required to support incomplete types. Some of the smart pointers do allow incomplete types. Off-hand I can't think of anything else which would allow incomplete types. A quick search for "incomplete" yields the following components allowing incomplete types as template arguments:

- `std::declval<T>()`
- `std::unique_ptr<T>`
- `std::default_delete<T>`
- `std::shared_ptr<T>`
- `std::weak_ptr<T>`
- `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>`

In the code example, `std::map<int, A>::iterator` instantiates a template with an incomplete type. As a result the code results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Vector, list, and forward_list support incomplete types.

Comment: @Barry: Is there a complete list of these somewhere?

Comment: @Dani [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/containers), search _incomplete_ and you'll find them (I mean, the three containers mentioned by @Barry).

Comment: @Barry: can you pount at the section stating that? Those I mentioned specifically mention that incomplete type are allowed.

Comment: @DietmarKühl [`forward_list`](http://eel.is/c++draft/forwardlist.overview#4), [`list`](http://eel.is/c++draft/list.overview#3), and [`vector`](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.overview#3)

Comment: Judging from the date on the document it is taken from a draft for C++17. It is possible that the guarantees were tightened. I have checked C++14 which specifies the currently active standard. The C++17 draft isn't relevant, yet.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thus the OP's code should fail as well if you use a `list` instead of a `map`, according with what you are saying. Anyway it compiles. Is that a bug of the _libc++_ implementation?

Comment: @skypjack: Undefined behavior is undefined. It might not work, but it might also work as expected.

Comment: @Dani Well, _compile_ and _work_ are very different concepts. In one case it doesn't compile, while in the other it compiles and has undefined behavior? It may be, just curious.

Comment: @skypjack: I think a compiler is allowed to reject a program with undefined behavior.

Comment: @skypjack: when the program has undefined behavior the compiler is allowed to not compile the code. However, it isn't mansated to do so it can compile the code and an implementation is even allowed to give the undefined behavior some specified meaning. Since instantiation is a compike-time thing it is more likely to fail compilation than it is for some other forms of undefined behavior.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: This can also result in runtime undefined behavior, as C style cast can behave differently depending on whether the types are defined.